# Read or parse an array data from mysql array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, parsing, get

Im trying to parse or read the model_name and the link image from an option_value in the mysql table, to the array `$atts['vehicle_models'] as $tab` but is not working with the next code, is there something wrong?:

```
$query = "SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='fw_extensions'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

```
 $array = array(
        'vehicle_title' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Title', 'fw' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Enter the title . %s for make text normal.  if you dont use %s text will be display bold', 'fw' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => 'Vehicle Models - Our rental fleet at a glance'
        ),
        'vehicle_models' => array(
            'type' => 'addable-popup',
            'label' => __( 'Vehicle Models', 'fw' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Add Vehicle Models', 'fw' ),
            'template' => '{{=model_name}}',
            'popup-options' => array(
                'model_name' => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Model Name', 'fw' ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Add Vehicle Model Name', 'fw' ),
                    'type' => 'text',
                ),
                'image' => array(
                    'type' => 'upload',
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Upload image.',
                    'desc' => __( 'Upload model image.  Size 500px 280px', 'fw' ),
                ),
                'rent_rate' => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Rate', 'fw' ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Add rent per day', 'fw' ),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'value' => '$ 37.40'
                ),
                'perday' => array(
                    'label' => __( 'perday', 'fw' ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Add rent per day', 'fw' ),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'value' => 'rent per day'
                ),
                'vehicle_details' => array(
                    'type' => 'addable-popup',
                    'label' => __( 'Vehicle Feature', 'fw' ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Add Vehicle Feature', 'fw' ),
                    'template' => '{{=feature}}',
                    'popup-options' => array(

                    'feature' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => 'feature',
                    ),
                    'feature_details' => array(
                        'label' => __( 'Feature Details', 'fw' ),
                        'desc' => __( 'Feature Details', 'fw' ),
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
//          'reserve_button' => array(
//              'label' => __( 'Link', 'fw' ),
//              'desc' => __( 'Add rent per day', 'fw' ),
//              'type' => 'text',
//              'value' => '$ 37.40 rent per day'
//          )
        ),
    ),
);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

fw_print( $array );
?>

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

fw_print( $array );
?>
```

And here is the value of the array in the mysql, I know is to large but more details -better:

```
a:4:{s:13:"contact-forms";a:2:{s:40:"contact-forms-contact-form-5545b6415b3e6";a:9:{s:5:"width";s:3:"1_1";s:2:"id";s:26:"contact-form-5545b6415b3e6";s:4:"form";a:1:{s:4:"json";s:2046:"[{"type":"form-header-title","shortcode":"form_header_title","width":"","options":{"title":"You have any questions or need additional information? ","subtitle":"%s Address : Car|Rental \/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/localhost:8888\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/carrental\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 3861 Sepulveda Blvd. \/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/localhost:8888\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com/carrental\/\/myweb.com\//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ Culver City, CA 90230 %s "}},{"type":"text","shortcode":"text_cf5246f","width":"1_2","options":{"label":"","required":true,"placeholder":"First Name","default_value":"","constraints":{"constraint":"characters","characters":{"min":"0","max":""},"words":{"min":"0","max":""}},"info":""}},{"type":"text","shortcode":"text_2475f6b","width":"1_2","options":{"label":"","required":true,"placeholder":"Last Name","default_value":"","constraints":{"constraint":"characters","characters":{"min":"0","max":""},"words":{"min":"0","max":""}},"info":""}},{"type":"text","shortcode":"text_126578e","width":"1_2","options":{"label":"","required":true,"placeholder":"Telephone","default_value":"","constraints":{"constraint":"characters","characters":{"min":"0","max":""},"words":{"min":"0","max":""}},"info":""}},{"type":"text","shortcode":"text_8ffa67b","width":"1_2","options":{"label":"","required":true,"placeholder":"Email","default_value":"","constraints":{"constraint":"characters","characters":{"min":"0","max":""},"words":{"min":"0","max":""}},"info":""}},{"type":"textarea","shortcode":"textarea_e62cf15","width":"1_1","options":{"label":"","required":true,"placeholder":"Message","default_value":"","constraints":{"constraint":"characters","characters":{"min":"0","max":""},"words":{"min":"0","max":""}},"info":""}}]";}s:15:"subject_message";s:11:"New message";s:18:"submit_button_text";s:14:"Submit Message";s:15:"success_message";s:58:"Message sent! We will contact with you as soon as possible";s:15:"failure_message";s:26:"Oops something went wrong.";s:8:"email_to";s:21:"xpeedstudio@gmail.com";s:6:"mailer";a:3:{s:6:"method";s:6:"wpmail";s:4:"smtp";a:5:{s:4:"host";s:0:"";s:8:"username";s:5:"admin";s:8:"password";s:3:"123";s:6:"secure";s:2:"no";s:4:"port";s:0:"";}s:7:"general";a:2:{s:9:"from_name";s:18:"Car rental Service";s:12:"from_address";s:21:"xpeedstudio@gmail.com";}}}s:40:"contact-forms-contact-form-5552e99d57496";N;}s:7:"builder";a:4:{s:9:"templates";a:1:{s:12:"page-builder";a:2:{s:24:"55466250aad8a:1430676048";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:9:"Locations";s:4:"json";s:535:"[{"type":"simple","shortcode":"direction_map","atts":{"locationtitle":"Car Rental Locations","locations":[{"location":"Santa Monica - 2102 Lincoln Blvd"},{"location":"Santa Monica - 2102 Lincoln Blvd"},{"location":"Los Angeles - 5711 W Century Blvd"},{"location":"Las Vegas - 6401 Centennial Center Blvd"},{"location":"New York - 610 Warren St"},{"location":"Orlando - 2125 W Landstreet Rd"},{"location":"Washington - 50 Massachusetts Ave NE"},{"location":"Denver - 7800 E Tufts Ave"}],"markertitle":"Car Rental Station"},"_items":[]}]";}s:24:"556aca9cccce6:1433062044";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Vehicle model";s:4:"json";s:9239:"[{"type":"section","atts":{"is_fullwidth":false,"default_spacing":"yes","height":"auto","background_options":{"background":"none","color":{"background_color":""},"image":{"background_image":"","overlay_options":{"overlay":"no","yes":{"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.55)"}}},"video":{"video":"","overlay_options":{"overlay":"no","yes":{"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.55)"}}}},"class":""},"_items":[{"type":"simple","shortcode":"vehicle_tab","atts":{"vehicle_title":"Vehicle Models - Our rental fleet at a glance","vehicle_models":[{"model_name":"VW Golf VII","image":{"attachment_id":"16","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle1.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 37.40","perday":"rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Audi A1 S-LINE","image":{"attachment_id":"17","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle2.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 47.40","perday":"rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Toyota Camry","image":{"attachment_id":"18","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle3.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 50.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"BMW 320 ModernLine","image":{"attachment_id":"19","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle4.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 37.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Mercedes-Benz GLK","image":{"attachment_id":"20","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle5.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 80.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioningc","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"VW Passat CC","image":{"attachment_id":"21","url":"//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/wp-content//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/uploads//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/2015//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/05//myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/vehicle6.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 75.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases //myweb.com///myweb.com/localhost:8888//myweb.com/carrental//myweb.com/ 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]}]},"_items":[]}]}]";}}}s:16:"templates:column";a:1:{s:12:"page-builder";a:1:{s:32:"00345a89b9dab4c103c93653ec19f755";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"kontact";s:4:"json";s:2877:"{"type":"column","width":"2_3","atts":{"default_padding":"","html_label":"","padding_top":"0","padding_right":"0","padding_bottom":"0","padding_left":"0","background_options":{"background":"none","image":{"background_image":"","repeat":"no-repeat","bg_position_x":"left","bg_position_y":"top","bg_size":"auto","overlay_options":{"overlay":"no","yes":{"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.55)"}}},"bgcolor":{"background_color":""}},"txtcolor":"","tablet":"","offset":"","class":""},"_items":[{"type":"simple","shortcode":"special_heading","atts":{"title":"Contact Us","heading":"h1","subtitle":"","centered":false,"color":"","separator":{"show_separator":"no"},"class":""},"_items":[]},{"type":"contact-form","atts":{"id":"contact-form-5552e99d57496","form":{"json":"[{\"type\":\"form-header-title\",\"shortcode\":\"form_header_title\",\"width\":\"\",\"options\":{\"title\":\"You have any questions or need additional information? \",\"subtitle\":\"%sAddress : %s Re|Nt \\/ 7 Voznesenskiy Pereulok  Moscow  125009  Russian Federation \"}},{\"type\":\"text\",\"shortcode\":\"text_29da52c\",\"width\":\"1_2\",\"options\":{\"label\":\"\",\"required\":true,\"placeholder\":\"First Name\",\"default_value\":\"\",\"constraints\":{\"constraint\":\"characters\",\"characters\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"},\"words\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"}},\"info\":\"\"}},{\"type\":\"text\",\"shortcode\":\"text_e89f2de\",\"width\":\"1_2\",\"options\":{\"label\":\"\",\"required\":true,\"placeholder\":\"Last Name\",\"default_value\":\"\",\"constraints\":{\"constraint\":\"characters\",\"characters\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"},\"words\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"}},\"info\":\"\"}},{\"type\":\"text\",\"shortcode\":\"text_f441a9a\",\"width\":\"1_2\",\"options\":{\"label\":\"\",\"required\":true,\"placeholder\":\"Telephone\",\"default_value\":\"\",\"constraints\":{\"constraint\":\"characters\",\"characters\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"},\"words\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"}},\"info\":\"\"}},{\"type\":\"text\",\"shortcode\":\"text_c296f0d\",\"width\":\"1_2\",\"options\":{\"label\":\"\",\"required\":true,\"placeholder\":\"Email\",\"default_value\":\"\",\"constraints\":{\"constraint\":\"characters\",\"characters\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"},\"words\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"}},\"info\":\"\"}},{\"type\":\"textarea\",\"shortcode\":\"textarea_b8dadc3\",\"width\":\"1_1\",\"options\":{\"label\":\"\",\"required\":true,\"placeholder\":\"Message\",\"default_value\":\"\",\"constraints\":{\"constraint\":\"characters\",\"characters\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"},\"words\":{\"min\":\"0\",\"max\":\"\"}},\"info\":\"\"}}]"},"subject_message":"New message","submit_button_text":"Submit Message","success_message":"Message sent! We will contact with you as soon as possible","failure_message":"Oops something went wrong.","email_to":"carrental@gmail.com","mailer":{"time":1454405086}},"_items":[]}]}";}}}s:10:"fullscreen";a:0:{}s:17:"templates:section";a:1:{s:12:"page-builder";a:1:{s:32:"f0fd9af6b821d48f129c35ecfb50ad92";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"prueba1";s:4:"json";s:4578:"{"type":"section","atts":{"is_fullwidth":false,"default_spacing":"yes","height":"auto","background_options":{"background":"none","color":{"background_color":""},"image":{"background_image":"","overlay_options":{"overlay":"no","yes":{"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.55)"}}},"video":{"video":"","overlay_options":{"overlay":"no","yes":{"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.55)"}}}},"class":""},"_items":[{"type":"simple","shortcode":"tabs","atts":{"tabs_position_picker":{"tabs_type":"one","one":{"tabs_justified":""},"three":{"tabs_justified":""}},"tabs":[{"tab_title":"All types","tab_icon":"","tab_content_title":"","tab_content":""},{"tab_title":"Ecomon-class","tab_icon":"","tab_content_title":"","tab_content":""},{"tab_title":"Business-class","tab_icon":"","tab_content_title":"","tab_content":""},{"tab_title":"Executive-class","tab_icon":"","tab_content_title":"","tab_content":""},{"tab_title":"Micro-bus","tab_icon":"","tab_content_title":"","tab_content":""}],"class":""},"_items":[]},{"type":"simple","shortcode":"vehicle_tab","atts":{"vehicle_title":"Vehicle Models - Our rental fleet at a glance","vehicle_models":[{"model_name":"VW Golf VII","image":{"attachment_id":"16","url":"//carrentalwordpresstheme.net/demo1/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle1.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 37.40","perday":"rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Audi A1 S-LINE","image":{"attachment_id":"17","url":"//carrentalwordpresstheme.net/demo1/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle2.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 47.40","perday":"rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Toyota Camry","image":{"attachment_id":"18","url":"//carrentalwordpresstheme.net/demo1/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle3.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 50.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"BMW 320 ModernLine","image":{"attachment_id":"19","url":"//carrentalwordpresstheme.net/demo1/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle4.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 37.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"Mercedes-Benz GLK","image":{"attachment_id":"20","url":"//carrentalwordpresstheme.net/demo1/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle5.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 80.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioningc","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]},{"model_name":"LEXUS Passat CC","image":{"attachment_id":"21","url":"//myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/vehicle6.jpg"},"rent_rate":"$ 75.40","perday":"Rent per day","vehicle_details":[{"feature":"Model","feature_details":"Limousine"},{"feature":"Doors","feature_details":"4"},{"feature":"Seats","feature_details":"5"},{"feature":"Luggage","feature_details":"2 Suitcases / 2 Bags"},{"feature":"Transmission","feature_details":"Automatic"},{"feature":"Air conditioning","feature_details":"Yes"},{"feature":"Minimum age","feature_details":"25 years"}]}]},"_items":[]}]}";}}}}s:11:"seo-sitemap";a:2:{s:10:"last_modif";a:1:{s:19:"last_sitemap_update";i:1431277204;}s:6:"update";i:1455500501;}s:6:"backup";a:2:{s:8:"settings";a:1:{s:22:"cron_full-completed_at";i:1454406669;}s:13:"wp_upload_dir";a:6:{s:4:"path";s:62:"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/carrental/wp-content/uploads/2015/09";s:3:"url";s:50:"http://myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09";s:6:"subdir";s:8:"/2015/09";s:7:"basedir";s:54:"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/carrental/wp-content/uploads";s:7:"baseurl";s:42:"http://myweb.com/wp-content/uploads";s:5:"error";b:0;}}}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or are you receiving that string 'a:4:{s:13:"conta...'?

Comment: Whence the `_($a,$b)` function? Is this Joomla? Thanks.

Comment: this is wordpress. Im not getting errors, Im getting that large string

Comment: this is the php code, here is not connected to the mysql but has to be something in the selector, If there were a mysql database connection: https://jsfiddle.net/lordzeph/v0eftu8m/1/#&togetherjs=zhSmt4cQwQ